# Smooth lofted surface with Matlab isosurface

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I'm trying to generate a 3D structure from a set of 2D cross sections in Matlab- in my case it's a wing that I've optimized the structure for. For the simple example I have two cross sections that are not identical. They can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J23dd.png).

Now I want to do a loft between the surfaces and put caps on the ends, which I do with isosurface and isocaps, respectively. Since I don't want the vague contours, I include a threshold

```
threshold=0.6;

% loft
fv=isosurface(xq,yq,zq,vq,threshold);

%lids
fvc=isocaps(xq,yq,zq,vq,threshold);
fvc.faces = fvc.faces + size(fv.vertices,1); %re-numbering

%structure with nodes and elements of surface+lids
fall.faces = [fv.faces; fvc.faces];
fall.vertices = [fv.vertices; fvc.vertices];
```

Now, if I call  patch to plot it: `pall=patch(fall)`, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeQLD.png).

Can anybody tell me why the outer surface is not smooth? And even better, can anyone provide a solution to the issue?
Is it simply that the spacing between the cross sections is too large?

EDIT: Just to clarify. The edge in the middle on the 3d plot is not wanted. I have no idea why it is there. As this is a wing, it's supposed to simply connect the 2d cross sections. There is no data in that region, only at z=2.5m and z=7.5m, as indicated by the cross sections figure.

Comment: It looks smooth to me...

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]. Looking at this, Id say that its because of your data